# How do I have a windows batch file look through hundreds of folders and move files around based on a list.txt?

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file, copy, move

I cant seem to get this to work. I need a batch file to go through a bunch of folders with files in them and move them to folders specified in the list .txt.

Basically I want it to do the following:
sample list.txt

```
folder1 file1
folder2 file1
```

and parse that so that i can:

```
copy C:\folder1\file1*.txt to destination folder
copy C:\folder2\file1*.txt to destination folder
etc
```

Here is what I have so far:

Main program:

```
echo off
set lines=0

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (%CD%\list.txt) do (
                echo %%a
                echo 1 %SN% from EEN %EEN%               
                call :first %%a
                echo 2 %SN% from EEN %EEN%               
                call :second %%a
                echo 3 %SN% from EEN %EEN%               
                set /a lines+=1
)

echo %lines%
pause
goto :eof

:first
set EEN=%1
goto :eof

:second
set SN=%2
goto :eof

pause
```

list.txt (first column is folder name, second is file name):

```
DM5V37H WMC1F0077774
DM5V37H WMC1F0077711
DM5V37H WMC1F0086480
DM5V37H WMC1F0086372
DM5V37H WMC1F0077655
DM5V37H WMC1F0077770
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using powershell for this, instead?

Comment: I am not very familiar with PowerShell (only used it for Exchange and MS servers).  Is this something that cant be done due to Batch limitations?

Comment: I'm sure you could eventually figure it out.  I just think it would be much simpler to write and debug in PowerShell. You could probably do using one-fourth of the lines above.  It sounds like you already have a good start with your experience with Exchange, etc.   There's lots of good reference information and tutorials online, including on stackoverflow. Give it a shot!

Comment: Ok, will try! Thanks.... since my PowerShell experience is within Exchange Powershell window... how do I even execute it? Whats the best thing to write it in? Ive just used Notepad before (or Notepad++). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have powershell installed.  If you are using Win 7, then its installed with the system.  If you are using XP, then you will need to download and install from Microsoft.  You can create scripts in any text editor, just like batch files.  The only difference is that you save it with a ".ps1" extension.  Next, launch powershell.  On my system, its located in `Start=>Programs=>Accessories=>WindowsPowershell`.  Use navigation commands to navigate to your script, then run it, just as you would a batch file.  You can also enter commands directly on the command line.

Comment: Here's a [forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/ac293787-b687-4694-b68b-ac9420edb370) that discusses your issue.

Comment: Here's a [good tutorial on powershell](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5a8d2641e0963a97&id=5A8D2641E0963A97%216929&sc=documents).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your references to SN and EEN, but I just tested this and it seems to work.  The first section is a demonstration of how to access each item in a line read from the file, then the actual move operation is performed.  I'm sure you can modify it to your needs.

```
@echo off
set lines=0

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (list.txt) do echo %%a %%b&set /a lines+=1
echo Number of lines: %lines%

:: Perform move operation.  
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (list.txt) do (
if not exist %%a (md %%a)
move "%%b" "%%a\%%b"
)
```